# how to make the correspondence between Beans and concrete classes derived from abstract one

Tags: java, javabeans

My question is:

Let's say I have a `User.java`, `Bid.java`, and `Auction.java` (Object Relational Mapping between them). `Auction.java` has its corresponding Bean (which implements its interface). But, if I want to add a new `Auction` type (I've implemented the English one, I also want the Dutch type) how to make to correct structure?

Logically, both English and Dutch have stuff in common so an abstract class for them would be essential. But should I make a Bean for every concrete auction class?

I'm using JSF with primefaces for front-end.

Answer (score 0):

> But should I make a Bean for every concrete auction class or how
>   should I correctly proceed?

No, they should follow the following relationships.

```
public abstract class Auction implements Auctionable {
    //common things
}

public class EnglishAuction extends Auction {
    //EnglishAuction details
}

public class DutchAuction extends Auction {
    //DutchAuction details
}
```

Comment: OK.. but I need to implement Beans because i'm working with CDI Beans currently. so, how can I map Entities with auction's corresponding bean ?